# Need to allocate memory for both a 2D tuple array and a 2D pointer array of unknown size?

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic, malloc, 2d

first ever question on here so sorry if I miss anything.
I am trying to model a 2D electrostatic problem in Physics with C.
I have a main array on which I will store value of potential and charge density at each point then a pointer array which will give the memory addresses to the main array.

However I do not know the array size at compile time as it is user input at runtime so therefore need to be able to dynamically allocate the memory.
Here's what I have already, any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

typedef struct tTuple { //Create new type called tuple
    double poten; //potential
    double cden; //charge density
} tuple;



int i, j;
int N, M;
#define a 10 //Grid Width
#define b 10 //Grid Height
int x1, y1, x2, y2; //Positions of two point charges
int my_rank, comm_size;
double w;

tuple  mainarray [a][b];
double *pointerarray[a][b];
int convflag = 1;  //Global convergence checker flag


/* More code below with main function containing scanf etc */
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use malloc or calloc to dynamically allocate the memory. I'll assume here that a and b have been obtained from the user:

```
tTuple * main_array;
```

And in your setup function put

```
main_array = calloc(a*b, sizeof(tTuple));
```

For error checking, test that main_array is not NULL. To get an element, use

```
main_array[i*b+j]
```

I'm not sure how you were planning to use the pointer array - is it really needed? main_array has the element memory locations.

Comment: Hey ehaymore, thanks for you answer.
Yeah I'm going to need the pointer array for later as I'm parallelising the code with MPI.
I'm not quite sure about the main_array[i*b+j] what exactly does that mean?

Comment: What you get from calloc is an pointer that can be used as a 1-d array. Since you need a  2-d array, you need to convert the matrix indices to a 1-d index yourself: the row index times the number of coumns plus the column index. And then look that computed 1-d index up in main_array.

Comment: Ahh, I understand. Thanks so much for you help!